# Problems upgrading MySQL application from Delphi 2006 to 2010

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-2010, dbexpress, libmysql

I upgraded my Delphi to 2010 version and I tried to open and run application written in Delphi 2006. The app is using mysql by dbexpress with libmysql.dll and a second driver found somewhere on the Internet.

I can't run it on 2010. I'm always getting "missing libmysql.dll library". I tried to get new version of it but it didn't help. Copying this library into almost all system directories didn't help.

I'm out of any ideas what to do, how do I connect to database :(

Answer (score 1):

It's most probably a unicode problem. PChar is no longer a pointer to an ansistring, but a pointer to a unicodestring. Try and upgrade the dbexpress driver. I don't mean the dll, but the dbexpress wrapper code. I'd need a little more information to help further though.

Comment: should'nt be dbexpress in latest version installed with new delphi? i'll try to upgrade it

Answer (score 0):

check you have dbxmys.dll available to your app too (in the exe dir or on the path)